# Parsing and saving Json response values - Django

Tags: json, django

I have a django project that sent a json request and now I am getting json back. There are certain values from the json reponse that I want to save into a model that I created that will store the information gathered. I couldnt find a way to parse the data and save the data that was taken... Here is a sample response that I am using which has information that I want to extract...

```
{  
   '_id':'..e154e57',
   '_links':{  
      'self':{  
         'href':'https://uat-api.synapsefi.com/v3.1/users/..002e154e57'
      }
   },
   'client':{  
      'id':'..1026a34',
      'name':'Charlie Brown LLC'
   },
   'doc_status':{  
      'physical_doc':'MISSING|INVALID',
      'virtual_doc':'MISSING|INVALID'
   },
   'documents':[  

   ],
   'emails':[  

   ],
   'extra':{  
      'cip_tag':1,
      'date_joined':1504774195147,
      'extra_security':False,
      'is_business':True,
      'last_updated':1504774195147,
      'public_note':None,
      'supp_id':'123abc'
   },
   'is_hidden':False,
   'legal_names':[  
      'Hello McHello'
   ],
   'logins':[  
      {  
         'email':'hello@synapsepay.com',
         'scope':'READ_AND_WRITE'
      }
   ],
   'permission':'UNVERIFIED',
   'phone_numbers':[  
      '555-555-5555'
   ],
   'photos':[  

   ],
   'refresh_token':'..C1tdG8LPqF6'
}
```

sample peices of information I want are id, sip, supp, joined, refresh tocken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
import json

my_dict = json.loads(my_json_response)
```

You should get a dictionary to work with.

Comment: how can i grab values by the key... what is the syntax for that... @Tico

Comment: really??  my_dict['id'] gets the id. Anyway I strongly suggest you do any python tutorial in internet. You learn about dictionaries on any python 101 class

Comment: I ran the following code = `response = json.loads(user)
    if response:
        _id = response['_id']
        name = response.client['name']
        link = response._links.self['href']
        cip = response.extra['cip_tag']
        supp = response.extra['supp_id']
        print(name)
        print(_id)
        print(link)
        print(cip)
        print(supp)` and got the following error `TypeError at /setup_profile/
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'User'`@Tico